# node js is not working nodemon code any one know answer?

Tags: node.js, nodemon

nodemon : File C:\Users\Safran\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see
about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

- nodemon new
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
  ```

what is the solution to problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running this script in your PowerShell to enable execution;
This command sets the execution policy to "RemoteSigned" for the current user, which allows the execution of locally created scripts but requires downloaded scripts to be signed by a trusted publisher.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

Then you run nodemon again